# Joining columns of one row as a single ouput in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have a member table with separate columns for the first, middle and last name:

```
id,firstname,middlename,lastname,role,photo
```

How can I retrieve the complete name with one query? I tried using the `AS` keyword, but I don't know how to combine those 3 columns into one:

```
SELECT id,lastname AS name FROM members ORDER BY role
```

For example I want to retrieve the full name (ie First, middle and last name) as `name` with of course a space in between each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) or [concat_ws](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) as @491243 has shown in his answer.  Here is how you can use `concat` function.

```
select id, concat(firstname, ' ', middlename, ' ', lastname) as name, role, photo 
from members 
order by role;
```

Answer (score 3):

use [**CONCAT_WS( )**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, middlename, lastname) AS Name
FROM   members 
ORDER  BY role
```

From DOCS,

> CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special
>   form of CONCAT(). The first argument is the separator for the rest of
>   the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be
>   concatenated. The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the
>   arguments. If the separator is NULL, the result is NULL.